# Display a full screen image 100% height and 100% width but able to scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a full screen image that let's me scroll down the page like on the apple site here.

http://www.apple.com/uk

You'll notice that by resizing the browser the image stays full screen but it allows you to scroll down to the footer.

Can this be done in jquery or does it need javascript?

The only bit of code i have so far is this css code that make the image full screen:

```
.content {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: url("http://america.aljazeera.com/content/ajam/watch/shows/the-stream/the-stream-officialblog/2013/9/16/indiana-ag-callsfordrugtestingofpregnantwomen/jcr:content/blog/mainpar/adaptiveimage/src.adapt.960.high.1379636395676.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
         -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
}
```

and here's a fiddle fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XXHgJ/

if you scroll down the footer shows but the menu stays still, this needs to scroll up.

Comment: What menu is staying still? I only see the background and the footer

Comment: Apple has placed the image in a div then played around with css positioning to place the top menu. Once the image is in a div,  you will be dealing with the div element not the image as BackGround... iF YOU send the image to the Background it will have no effect onScroll

Comment: @pete, sorry for the confusion, i want the image to slide up when the footer slides up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to make a full screen element, you could do it with jQuery:

**jQuery:**

```
function setDimensions(){
   var windowsHeight = $(window).height();
   $('#element').css('height', windowsHeight + 'px');
}

//when resizing the site, we adjust the heights of the sections
$(window).resize(function() {
    setDimensions();
});

setDimensions();
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    background-image: url(yourURL);
    background-size:cover;

}
```

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XXHgJ/7/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've only started to learn jquery last week and your script is still a little advanced for me, is there any chance you can update my fiddle, i've tried but with no luck. Here's my effort http://jsfiddle.net/XXHgJ/5/ . From what i undertstand of your code, the variable windowsheight get's the height of the browser, what about width? the second part adds the height in css, the last bit confuses me...

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle but it's not quite right, the image doesn't appear to stretch the full screen and it doesn't scroll when the footer scrolls up

Comment: Because of your CSS. You should delete the `fixed` position of your background and add a `background-size: cover` if you want the background to fill the div: http://jsfiddle.net/XXHgJ/7/

Comment: thank you so much, i edited the code slightly here http://jsfiddle.net/XXHgJ/12 so the image stays in centre, but it now works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this?... I did it with pure css after closely noticing that in the one for apple when the page resizes, the image size does not necessarily change.

```
<div>

    <div style="position:relative; background:green; ">
     <div style="position:absolute; top:30px; left:50px; margin:auto; width:250px; height:40px; text-align:center; padding-top:10px; background:black; color:#fff;">Menu goes here</div>
        <div><img src="http://america.aljazeera.com/content/ajam/watch/shows/the-stream/the-stream-officialblog/2013/9/16/indiana-ag-callsfordrugtestingofpregnantwomen/jcr:content/blog/mainpar/adaptiveimage/src.adapt.960.high.1379636395676.jpg" height="400" /></div></div>

    <div style="background:#fff; padding:30px;">Footer</div>


</div>
```

See Feddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HZbAt/

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle but it's not quite right, the images doesn't appear to be full screen and it doesn't scroll.

Comment: Of course It is...You can let the image be 100% in either height or width using css or jQury... NOTE that Apples images are High quality VERY LARGE IMAGES... If you get such an image that is rectangular just as the ones used by Apple... the Code I sent you should Work perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

on my page i have margin-top 80px which pushes the content down is their anything i can add to the code so this does not happen like -80px? This is for the jquery script